# when to make a port dynamic desirable instead of trunk?

Tags: cisco, trunk

i'm reading CCNA stuff and just got stuck in this issue:
i read some articles about DTP and trunking but didn't understand when to make a port **trunk** and when make it **dynamic desirable** ?
in what case you may want a port be sometime access and sometime in trunk mode ? and why you may want a port just receive a trunk and not send it (in the case of being  `port mode dynamic auto`)

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cisco created DTP in large part to make configuration easy or more flexible, way back in the innocent days when security was not a big concern.

But modern good practice is to set the switch port statically- either access or trunk- to prevent someone from getting access to VLANS that they shouldn’t.